# Error using MUI components - Can't resolve @mui/material

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I can't seem to get a basic mui button to work properly, any ideas what's wrong here?

```
react_1     | ERROR in ./src/components/formSubmit.js 6:0-39
react_1     | Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material' in '/app/frontend/src/components'
```

However, it does appear to be installed:

```
npm ls
frontend@0.1.0 /path/to/myapp/frontend
├── @emotion/react@11.11.3
├── @emotion/styled@11.11.0
├── @mui/icons-material@5.15.10
├── @mui/material@5.15.10
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.17.0
├── @testing-library/react@13.4.0
├── @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0
├── axios@1.6.7
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react-scripts@5.0.1
├── react@18.2.0
└── web-vitals@2.1.4
```

and the folders look to be in node_modules:

```
ls node_modules | grep mui
@mui
```

All I'm doing is the following to get the error:

```
import {Button} from '@mui/material';
```

Comment: It says ```Can't resolve ... in '/app/frontend/src/components'```. Seems like it is looking in components, not in node_modules. Do you use vite? Could it be a conflict with vite aliases?

Comment: Oh that's odd. No, I don't, though I'm using docker. Do I need to put a relative path to node_modules?

Comment: Or should I be converting everything to typescript? I get the following still: 

 TS2307: Cannot find module '@mui/material' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: To be clear I used create-react-app, perhaps it's just broken?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my issue was just that my node_modules mapping with docker was all wrong, I had it in the wrong place so node_modules wasn't showing up in the docker container.

Best way to check is to exec into the docker container and see node_modules is in the correct place.

I ended up switching to vite while i was at it, anyway.